# PHP WebService Call from other language

Tags: service

If webservices created using PHP,Is that web service can be call from any other language like Intersystems Cache Or GTM..etc.and call from anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a true [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), it can been consumed by any language that can access it.

Web services are about *inter operating* between languages and platform, so they can be consumed by a wide range of those.